# android - tablet not using values-sw600dp and layout-sw600dp folders

Tags: android, android-resources, tablet, android-screen-support

I have an app which I have a layout for tablet, and its different from the phone layout.

I have my `home.xml` in both the `layout` and the `layout-sw600dp`, and also I have a file named `screen.xml` with a boolean value indicating if the device is a phone or a tablet.

**/res/values-sw600dp/screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

**/res/values/screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isTablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Now I am running the app on a tablet (model: [alcatel i213 tablet](http://img.kasa.cz/k-foto/800/4/5/1/product_1848154.jpg)) and the tablet is using the default **values** and **layout** folders.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to [this device](http://www.gsmarena.com/alcatel_pixi_7-6164.php), there may be no problem. That device probably does not have a smallest width bigger than 600dp. I would expect that its smallest width would be about 540dp, given its screen resolution (540px x 960px) and density (~157 dpi, which should map to `mdpi`, where 1px=1dp).

Comment: haha yeah I fixed it right after I posted the question. used values/sw-520dp and it  worked:). will accept your answer in a sec

Answer (score -2):

I had folder " values-sw600dp" instead of "values-sw600dp". So, incorrect name of the folder can be the cause.